# Highcharts / Highstock: How to access values at the centers of dataGroups of another series

Tags: highcharts

In Highstock, a series of densely sampled data points is plotted with arearange style and dataGrouping. Now, I need to get access to the values at each of the *group centers* to overplot it as a new series, which will be used to track the central values of the first one.

So, in the plotOptions configuring the chart, I need access to the grouped data in the first series in order to construct the data grid of the second one.

Here is an attempt which does not yet do it: http://jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/ts10vpyL/

```
  let center_data = []; // the line data series to be constructed

  window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      width: 150 // make it narrow in order to get some point grouping
    },

    series: [{ // first series is arearange spanning min,max of the group
      name: 'data',
      data: data,
      type: 'arearange',
      color: "blue",
      dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        approximation: function (a) { // using this to construct the center_data
          center_data.push([a[Math.floor(a.length / 2.0)], // y at the center of the group
          this.xData[Math.floor(a.length / 2.0)] // x at the center of the group (not working)
          ]
          );
          return [Math.min(...a), Math.max(...a)];  // like the default approximation for grouped data
        }
      }
    },

    { // second series should be the values at the center of the groups.
      name: 'center', // should be one point at the center of the group in the previous series. 
                      // per default it is first value in the group but I need the central one  
      data: data,  **// I don't want this!! I want the center_data !!! **
      type: "line",
      color: "red"
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Use the `render` callback to get access to the `groupedData`. Render callback triggers after each chart redraw,
2. Calculate the newData, base on the `groupedData` array,
3. Do an update of the existing line series, but remember to do it with using the `chartRedraw` flag to avoid the infinity loop,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ev74x6nr/

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  events: {
    render() {
      let chart = this,
        baseSeries = chart.series[0],
        groupedData = baseSeries.groupedData,
        newData;

      newData = groupedData.map(value => {
        let x = value.x,
          y = (value.low + value.high) / 2;


        return [x, y]
      })

      if (chartRedraw) {
        chartRedraw = false;
        chart.series[1].update({
          data: newData,
        })
      }

      chartRedraw = true;
    }
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I am very grateful, thanks!